# Ionic ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="! item.open" it does not work

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-checkbox

I need to check the items "Not open" in an `ion-checkbox`, but the item I get from a server is `item.open`. When I click on the `ion-checkbox` it doesn't work correctly.

Does anyone have a solution?

```
ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="!item.open"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ionChange` method so you will be able to keep track of the value.